# Execute multiple commands via SSH and PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, cisco

I successfully managed to connect to a Cisco IE-2000-L switch via SSH. I used the [Renci SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) library.

Starting guide: http://vwiki.co.uk/SSH_Client_(PowerShell)

#### My working code is

```
# Load SSH library (for .NET 4.0 and PowerShell 3)
$DllPath = "D:\temp\Renci.SshNet.dll"
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path $DllPath) )

# Connect to switch (Cisco IE2000-L) with IP, port, username, password
$SshClient = New-Object Renci.SshNet.SshClient('172.20.91.30', 22, 'admin', 'mypassword')
$SshClient.Connect()

# execute one command on Cisco switch
$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('show arp')

# show result
$SshCommand.Result 

# close SSH connection
$SshCommand.Dispose()
$SshClient.Disconnect()
$SshClient.Dispose()
```

#### My problem is

The above code sends just one command. But I want to execute several commands consecutively without closing and reopening a session.

If I add a second command right after the first one

```
# execute one command on Cisco switch
$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('show arp')
$SshCommand = $SshClient.RunCommand('show start')
```

...the script hangs and never finishes. What am I doing wrong?

---

Minor relevant information

- My main goal is to send multiple commands at once to a Cisco switch
- I already [tried Plink together with batch `cmd` input](http://www.ipbalance.com/programming/ms-powershell/1061-powershell-script-to-save-cisco-configuration-by-ssh.html). It's not reliable enough. It works sometimes and sometimes not.
- I already tried [telnet scripting](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php). Too awkward.

Comment: I solved it with the methode described in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892705/935614