# Use sudo with SSH-Session from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, powershell-2.0, sudo

On my Windows computer I use [**SSH-Session**](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library) module on PowerShell and I want to use `sudo` in order to execute special command in my server.

But when I launch my `sudo` command through SSH-Session I have this error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

I don't want to use PuTTY or the `ssh` command, so the parameter `-l` is not the issue!

If it's possible I don't want to change the SSH server configuration.

*I want to know how to force the pseudo allocation tty in PowerShell?*

Thanks

Comment: Are you permitted to modify your sudoers file to allow a specific setting for this user? Basically SSH-Session is based on SSH.NET (http://sshnet.codeplex.com/). From what I know it doesn't support enabling psuedo-tty's (which I believe would solve this problem). So what you need to do is detailed in this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80159/1347  (I think... :)   )

Comment: In Linux console I can execute my sudo command with the same user without problem. I think it's not necessary to update `sudoers file` but an option (if it exists) on PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use the Open SSH exe, push by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases).

After launch `PowerShell` as administrator

```
ssh 192.168.1.123 -p 22 -l general03
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SSH-Session` module is based on [SSH.NET library](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).

The SSH.NET library does support pseudo terminal allocation, but the `SSH-Session` module does not expose the functionality.

You would have to modify `SSH-Session` code to make it available.

- Either use the `Shell` class (`SshClient.CreateShell`), which implicitly requests pseudo terminal.
- Or explicitly request pseudo terminal using the `ChannelSession.SendPseudoTerminalRequest`.

---

Or modify your [`sudoers` configuration file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) not to require pseudo terminal for `sudo` (remove the `requiretty` option, which is off by default, by the way).

---

Or use SSH.NET directly, without the `SSH-Session` module.

See these questions for some code:

- [Execute multiple commands via SSH and PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436507/850848)
- [PowerShell, read/write to SSH.NET streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19864617/850848)