# How to filter powershell ssh output

Tags: powershell, ssh, filter

I use the script described in [PowerShell, read/write to SSH.NET streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864617/powershell-read-write-to-ssh-net-streams/19892705#19892705) to get info from my firewall. However I need to isolate only 4 values.

edit "**test-connection1**"
    set vdom "**test1**"
    set ip 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping
    set inbandwidth **10000**
    set outbandwidth **10000**
edit "**test-connection2**"
    set vdom "**test1**"
    set ip 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping
    set inbandwidth **10000**
    set outbandwidth **10000**
--
edit "**test-connection3**"
    set vdom "**test2**"
    set ip 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping
    set inbandwidth **10000**
    set outbandwidth **10000**

I need to show only bold values. New row needs to be created on each "edit". The values can be separated by comma.

I need to get following result

```
test-connection,test1,10000,10000
test-connection2,test1,10000,10000
test-connection3,test2,10000,10000
```

How can I manipulate output created in function

```
function ReadStream($reader)
{
    $line = $reader.ReadLine();
    while ($line -ne $null)
    {
        $line
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each edit is predictable, you can do something like the following:

```
switch -Regex -File edit.txt {
  '^edit "(?<edit>[^"]+)"' {$edit = $matches.edit}
  '^set vdom "(?<vdom>[^"]+)"' {$vdom = $matches.vdom}
  '^set inbandwidth (?<inb>\d+)' {$inb = $matches.inb}
  '^set outbandwidth (?<outb>\d+)' { $edit,$vdom,$inb,$matches.outb -join ","}
}
```

`$matches` is an automatic variable that contains the result of string comparison using the `-match` operator. The variable is overwritten every time there is a successful match. Capture group values can be accessed by their names using the member access operator `.`. This is why you see the syntax `$matches.edit` to retrieve the value of the `edit` capture group.

The `switch` statement can read a file line-by-line using the `-File` parameter and perform regex matching using the `-Regex` parameter.

If the format of the edit entries are predictable, we can assume that we will always have an `edit`, `vdom`, `inbandwidth`, and `outbandwidth` lines in that order. That means we can assume we will have matches in that order and can therefore output all of the `edit` block matches once `outbandwidth` is matched.

The regular expressions (regexes) are the values within the single quotes on each line. Below is a breakdown of the two types of expressions used:

> **`^edit "(?<edit>[^"]+)"`**:
>
> - ^ asserts position at start of a line
> - edit matches the characters edit literally (case insensitive)
> - Named Capture Group edit (?[^"]+)
> - Match a single character not present in the list [^"]+, which means not a double quote character.
> - Quantifier (+) — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - " matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
>
> **`^set inbandwidth (?<inb>\d+)`**:
>
> - ^ asserts position at start of a line
> - set inbandwidth matches the characters set inbandwidth  literally (case insensitive)
> - Named Capture Group inb (?\d+)
> - \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
> - Quantifier (+) — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)